# Magento - "add to cart" button using static block does not add to cart

Tags: php, magento

I made an "add to cart" button using a static block.
I want to make a template which, when user click the cart button, adds the item to the cart like this:

[image]

How could i modify this template, especially the "onclick" part?

```
    <div class="actions">
    <?php if($_product->isSaleable()): ?>
        <button type="button" title="<?php echo $this->__('Add to Cart') ?>" class="button btn-cart" onclick="setLocation('<?php echo $this->getAddToCartUrl($_product) ?>')"><span><span><?php echo $this->__('Add to Cart') ?></span></span></button>
    <?php else: ?>
        <p class="availability out-of-stock"><span><?php echo $this->__('Out of stock') ?></span></p>
    <?php endif; ?>
</div>
```

Comment: How can i solve the add to cart button error, https://justpaste.it/6fi1f   Your code also not working.

Answer (score 0):

```
call phtml file in your static block using this
{{block type="core/template" template="catalog/product/custom.phtml"}}

$productId=4;(assign your product id here)
$_product=Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($productId);

<div class="actions">
    <?php if($_product->isSaleable()): ?>
        <button type="button" title="<?php echo $this->__('Add to Cart') ?>" class="button btn-cart" onclick="setLocation('<?php echo $this->getAddToCartUrl($_product) ?>')"><span><span><?php echo $this->__('Add to Cart') ?></span></span></button>
    <?php else: ?>
        <p class="availability out-of-stock"><span><?php echo $this->__('Out of stock') ?></span></p>
    <?php endif; ?>
</div>
```

Comment: How can i solve the add to cart button error, https://justpaste.it/6fi1f   Your code also not working.

Answer (score 0):

Replace your button html with the following code:

```
<button type="button" title="<?php echo $this->__('Add to Cart') ?>" class="button btn-cart" onclick="setLocation('<?php echo (string)Mage::helper('checkout/cart')->getAddUrl($_product);?>')"><span><span><?php echo $this->__('Add to Cart') ?></span></span></button>
```

Comment: How can i solve the add to cart button error, https://justpaste.it/6fi1f   Your code also not working.